# UserControl Width is Nan while it's ActualWidth set to the Column it placed on

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a UserControl, I do not set it's Width / Height, the UserControl has 2 TextBox inside a StackPanel.
when I place it in a Column where it's Width="Auto", the control stretches to fill the entire column, while the 2 TextBox maintain their Width (desire)
I want to keep the Control Width to it's Content Width, how to I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
```

This will keep the Control from stretching based on the container which it resides and instead will expand based on its contents if the `Width` is set to `Auto`.

MSDN provides an overview on [Alignment, Margins, and Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx) which may be of assistance.